# Where are the root method bodies in c#?

Tags: c#, methods

Where are the root method bodies in c#? How can I see it? I'm interested in how it works from the inside, but when I choose any class or method(f12) -

I see only a declaration, where is the body?
[image: where is the body?]

Comment: You might be able to find what you want on the [C# Reference Source site](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/) or the relevant area of the [dotnet runtime codebase on github](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime)

Comment: you can also use some decompiler, e.g. DotPeek, that creates the source-code from the assembly. However be aware that this is not the original source-code, so chances are it differes from what DotPeek gives you - e.g. concerning variable-names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because when you load an assembly (even the core dlls) you only get the compiled version and not the source code.

If you did, the assembly would be much larger than that.

Fortunatelly, the .NET Core code is open source so you can find it on [github](https://github.com/dotnet/core).

You can find the declaration of the partial struct [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Collections/ref/System.Collections.cs).